# android studio device connection problems

Tags: android-studio

I was able to connect my device to the android studio but when I removed HDD and shifted to SSD to make it perform better it is not recognizing my device although it is working smoother than before.
It is showing that it is not able to recognize the driver software in ADB interface settings but whenever I click on my device it says driver software is completely updated.
here are the images linked below:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTcgQ.jpg)

whenever I click on realme7 device inside portable devices(in device manager) it shows that driver software is completely updated.
please help me for the same.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html#Drivers)

Here they have mentioned phone model-wise drivers, download the one which is required.

Then go to `Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools Tab` and select the `Google USB Driver` & click OK
[Check this for the same](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb)

Comment: hey, Priyank thanks for your help buddy but I can't find a driver for realme phones

Comment: @Rohit for Realme devices you need to download the `Xiaomi` one.